# onPerformSync() method is not getting called

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I have implemented SyncAdapter using dummy account, but when I go to Settings --> Accounts --> MyApp, Sync is OFF there. I want this to sync automatically in 24 hours. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Where you create your dummy account, you then have to enable syncing and add a periodic sync to it. Like so:

```
final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.yourapp.authority";
final int SYNCABLE = 1;
final long SYNC_FREQUENCY_IN_SECONDS = 24 * 60 * 60; // once a day
ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account AUTHORITY, SYNCABLE);
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, AUTHORITY, true);
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, AUTHORITY, Bundle.EMPTY, 
    SYNC_FREQUENCY_IN_SECONDS);
```